# Can I suggest the order of RxJs forkJoin execution on the server?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In the following forkJoin code, I want requestTwo to execute only after requestOne has executed. Can this be done? From my tests, requestTwo completes before requestOne. Or is their an RxJs function that would ensure the order of execution?

```
forkJoin({
  requestOne: this.fillOrderService.changeOrderStatus({
    orderNo: this.orderNo,
    orderStatus: this.orderStatus,
    paymentIntent: paymentIntent,
    amount: this.processingOrder?.subtotal
  }),
  requestTwo: this.fillOrderService.getOrders('pending'),
}).subscribe(({ requestOne, requestTwo }) => {
  this.orders = requestTwo;
  this.orders = this.orders.filter(order => order._id !== this.processingOrder._id)

  this.processingOrder = requestOne;
  this.orderNo = this.processingOrder?._id;
  this.orderStatus = this.processingOrder?.status;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`combineLatest` executes all sources at the same time.

To fire your requests sequentially, you can chain them together using `pipe(switchMap())`.

```js
result$ = this.fillOrderService.changeOrderStatus(...).pipe(
    switchMap(requestOne => this.fillOrderService.getOrders('pending').pipe(
        map(requestTwo => ({ requestOne, requestTwo })
    ))
);
```

Here `switchMap` internally subscribes to the "inner" observable (`getOrders()`) and emits its results.  We can use `map` to transform the emission from the second request into an object that contains both response objects.